# Can't access links in block_view_alter hook

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a two-language site with the standard language switcher block. I want to remove the link that points to the current page language (I only want the user to see one link to switch to the language they're not seeing).

I've tried this:

```
function mymodule_block_view_language_block_alter(&$build, $block) {
  $build['links'] = []; //for now for debugging purposes, remove all links
}
```

It doesn't work (though it runs the code). The `$build` array doesn't have a `links` key, or anything it's supposed to according to the `build` method in `core/modules/language/src/Plugin/Block/LanguageBlock.php`. Why might this happen? How can I alter what I'm seeing there?

BTW I also tried the `block_build_alter` hook. Similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those hooks are unfortunately not very useful; I don't really know why they work like that. The actual block view didn't happen yet; that's in a preprocess. You'd need to add another preprocess that runs later.

However, for your specific use case, why not use the hook that's designed exactly for this? `hook_language_switch_links_alter()`?

Comment: I'll try that one, looks like exactly what I need. What would be the preprocess hook I'd use if that didn't work? And, do you know the purpose of the block hooks?

Comment: BTW the `language` module hook worked perfectly, it even allowed me to change the label by editing `$links[$language_id]['title']` (which I forgot to mention on the original question).